# Creating a dummy for if something occured in any row of the dataset in R

Tags: r

First of all I have to say that I am still new to coding and R, so this might be stupid question, but I couldn't find a question like this (maybe because I didn't know what to exactly search for)

I have a very large pagepath dataset containing clientID's and their browsing behavior on a website. I would like to make dummy variables for if a client saw a certain page. The problem is that I want this clientID to then have a 1 at every row that contains that particular clientID, and not just at the row where the clientID visited that page.

How my dataset looks like

```
  ClientID pagepath         
1 12345    /home  
2 12345    /test1
3 12345    /test2 
4 67890    /test1
5 67890    /home
6 54321    /test1
7 54321    /home
8 09876    /home
```

What I want as output:

```
  ClientID pagepath    dummy_test1     dummy_test2
1 12345    /home       1               1
2 12345    /test1      1               1
3 12345    /test2      1               1
4 67890    /test1      1               0
5 67890    /home       1               0
6 54321    /test2      0               1
7 54321    /home       0               1
8 09876    /home       0               0
```

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is `dummy_test1` and `dummy_test2` created ?

Comment: Hi Ronak, do you mean how they are created in my desired output? Because that is what I'm not sure of how to do

Comment: I am trying to code understand the logic to code for meaning why first 5 values in `dummy_test1` is 1 or why first 3 values of `dummy_test2` is 1?

Comment: Ah I see! Dummy_test1 is true (1) if the ClientID has /test1 anywhere in their pagepath and Dummy_test2 is true (1) if the ClientID has /test2 anywhere in their pagepath

Comment: Your row 6 is different in input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` `ClientID` and check for string `'test1'` and `'test2'` in `pagepath` and create two new columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ClientID) %>%
  mutate(dummy_test1 = +(any(grepl('test1', pagepath))), 
         dummy_test2 = +(any(grepl('test2', pagepath))))


#  ClientID pagepath dummy_test1 dummy_test2
#     <int> <fct>          <int>       <int>
#1    12345 /home              1           1
#2    12345 /test1             1           1
#3    12345 /test2             1           1
#4    67890 /test1             1           0
#5    67890 /home              1           0
#6    54321 /test1             1           0
#7    54321 /home              1           0
#8     9876 /home              0           0
```

`+` in front of `any` converts logical values (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) to integer values (`1`/`0`).

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!!! Was struggling with it for a while :-)